# Does orchard CMS/specially blog work with shared hosting?

Tags: orchardcms-1.8

If I look at current Orchard version then during configuration it ask for which type of site you want to configure.

1. Default
2. **Blog**
3. Corre

I want to install only the Blog module on GoDaddy shared hosting.

Does it work, as I have read on many article that it is not work with shared hosting? If not, is there a reason why it will not work with shared hosting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. In fact, I've had an Orchard site hosted on GoDaddy for about a year now. I did it under the Economy Windows Hosting with Plesk configuration. You'll probably have a rough start at first. Make sure you go into the host manager and set up support for ASP 4.5.2. I have had a rough time figuring out how to get sessions to persist. I solved this by setting up a session state server. Don't worry about that unless you run into problems with the site "logging off" unexpectedly though. (You may be in the middle of editing a blog post, for example, only to have it log you out after a very short time. It's really losing track of your session in the hosting farm of shared servers.)